# How can I type an array of mixed types in golang?

Tags: json, go, types, interface, hashmap

I'm writing out a map which I need to convert to JSON, and one of the required values is an array of mixed type.

```
var models = map[string]interface{} {
   ...
   "req": [[0, "all", [0]]],
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to assign a type to this nested array? Or is there a better approach for creating this JSON than a map?

**Edit:** Getting closer I think, unsure what to do about the nested arrays

```
var models = map[string]interface{} {
       ...
       "req": []interface{}{[[0, "all", [0]]]},
       ...
    }
```

**Edit:** The entire JSON I'm looking to create, I'm just stuck on the "req" key, but since it was requested:

```
{
    1388596687391: {
      veArs: [],
      name: 'Basic-f15d2',
      tags: ['Tag'],
      did: 1435588830424,
      usn: -1,
      req: [[0, 'all', [0]]],
      flds: [
        {
          name: 'Front',
          media: [],
          sticky: false,
          rtl: false,
          ord: 0,
          font: 'Arial',
          size: 20
        },
        {
          name: 'Back',
          media: [],
          sticky: false,
          rtl: false,
          ord: 1,
          font: 'Arial',
          size: 20
        }
      ],
      sortf: 0,
      latexPre:
        '\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\n\\special{papersize=3in,5in}\n\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n\\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}\n\\pagestyle{empty}\n\\setlength{\\parindent}{0in}\n\\begin{document}\n',
      tmpls: [
        {
          name: 'Card 1',
          qfmt: questionFormat,
          did: null,
          bafmt: '',
          afmt: answerFormat,
          ord: 0,
          bqfmt: ''
        }
      ],
      latexPost: '\\end{document}',
      type: 0,
      id: 1388596687391,
      css,
      mod: 1435645658
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please post a sample map and the format of json you want to create. Add more code to recreate the issue.

Comment: Added, though I think I'm just stuck on the nested arrays. Thanks!

Comment: How you are getting this data that you are saving to variable of map type. Show the variable data you are getting.

Comment: It's not coming from an API or anywhere externally, I need to manually create it to pass in as configuration for another library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice/array/map literals all work the same way, [as explained in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/20) - each value literal just needs the type specified when the containing type doesn't already specify the type (i.e. a map/slice/array of an interface type), and every list of values is enclosed in braces `{}`, not brackets `[]` as in JSON:

```
   "req": []interface{}{[]interface{}{[]interface{}{0, "all", []interface{}{0}}}},
```

Note that the last element could also be written as `[]int{0}`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! The inline approach is a little closer to what I was getting at. I think this is the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a basic example of doing it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  primes := [6]int {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
  mixed := []interface{} {"foo", 10, primes }
  //fmt.Println(mixed...)

  test := map[string]interface{} {
    "omar":mixed,
  }

  fmt.Println(test["omar"])
}
```

Comment: Ahh so an approach would be to define the nested types beforehand. Makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: This answer is correct, but doesn't attempt to explain *why* it's correct.

Comment: can you parse this? ie something like `fmt.Printf("%T, %v", mixed[2][1], mixed[2][1])` to output `int 3`